# Vue Cli не видит изображения в стилях компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Когда я запуская свой проект используя сборку `Vue Cli webpack simple` делая `npm run dev` изображения в стилях отображаются нормально, но когда я делаю `npm run build`, они не отображаются. Вот [конфигурация](https://codepen.io/nord18/pen/MLEqOY?editors=0010) моего вебпака. Так я указываю пути в стилях: `background: url('/src/assets/header-bg.png')`. В чем проблема?

Comment: Если искать изображения относительно `entry: './src/main.js'`, то скорее всего так: `background: url('assets/header-bg.png')`

Comment: Если делать так, то при npm run build оно ложит картинки в папку dist, но при запуске index.html они все равно не отображаются

Comment: К примеру, положите изображение в папку `public/images`, после сборки в корне `./dist` появляется папка `images`, соответственно, в `index.html` можем ссылаться `background: url('images/header-bg.png')`

Answer (score -1):

В webpack.config.js замени `publicPath: '/dist/'` на `publicPath: 'dist/'`.